# Configuring Media Server Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I setup a subdomain and created an alias in such a way that the subdomain displays same content as the main domain.
However, when I setup the subdomain in the media server section of my Prestashop, it completetly distort the display of the website.
I regenerated the .htaccess and cleared cache but it does not solve the problem.

How do I effectily setup the media server?

Comment: What do you mean by "distort the display" ? Check with your browser devTools the page for errors, if media assets are not loaded in the page it could be a CORS issue. Also make sure that is you have SSL enabled, you have a proper certificate for the media subdomain.

Comment: @user3256843 Thanks very much for your quick response. After enabling the SSL certificate for the subdomain, the website now fully loads without any problem. However, adding a media server did not optimize my Prestashop 1.7 speed.

Comment: Nice :) there are no speed improvements using media servers, unless you use a true "cdn" with asset compression systems with geo-localized replication and have a, ie., a website visited from all over the world.